# Cant find the right xpath on a website

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web

I am using selenium webdirver to log into a website and click a couple of buttons. The website that I want to connect to is twitch.tv. I can get it to click the log in button on top but cannot send keys to the username or password. It gives me an error when I try to use the username xpath of

```
//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/input
```

and the password xpath

```
//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[2]/input
```

Whenever I try these xpaths I get a *no such element exception*.

If someone could help me get the right xpaths for these elements that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The login form and it's inputs are *inside an `iframe`*. Switch to it first.

Java:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("passport-login");
```

Python:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("passport-login")
```

Comment: I just tried to switch to that jframe but it cannot find the iframe. It gives me an error that it cannot find an id by passport-login. Once I switch to that jframe what would the xpaths be for the username and password?

Comment: @Silber show the complete you have so far and we'll go from there. Thanks.